# Upgrade RAM in Samung NP550

Tags: laptop, upgrade

I've just purchased a new set of RAM for my Samsung series 5 laptop (NP550P7C) however (embarrassingly) cannot figure out how to get the laptop apart!  I've taken plenty of other models apart in the past however am struggling with this one.  I've removed all screws etc, however it seems that most of the cover is help in place by plastic clips which feel very flimsy and I don't want to force them without knowing what I am doing.  Has anyone replaced the RAM or HDD in one of these and have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to take the laptop apart. There is access on the bottom of the unit.

Page 82 of the [User Manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201211/20121107145929032/Win8_Manual_eng.pdf) shows how to upgrade your memory.

[image]

Comment: I had read that manual however it doesn't seem to match my laptop - the screw is there, as is the cover however it is a different shape (an inverted T rather than an L.  I can unclip the edges of this cover however it feels then as if it is being help with a screw from the other side which is the part I am unsure about forcing

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and pop the clips.  They feel firmly in place, but if you pry up the edges it will give.

How do I know? I've done it.

(Yeah, I expect you've long since abandoned this upgrade and/or figured out how to pop the cover off the bottom of your laptop, given that you had bought your fancy memory in 2012 and it's now mid-2015.  I just posted this necro answer in case others are in your place and find this page.)